# ModelBinder is not working after adding explicitly arguments to Html.BeginForm()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, modelbinder

In controller I obtain `StudentID` from POST method from a View. Basically the line is:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? StudentID) {}
```

In the View, I have a hidden field to provide the `StudentID`. What would be the reason that in View() when I changed the line:

```
using(Html.BeginForm()) { //... }
```

to

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Students", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

the `ModelBinder` stops binding `StudentID`. When I submit the form I receive `null` instead of correct Student's ID.

Comment: Can you include your full controller and view code?

Comment: Is the hidden field in your model definately populated? As previously it could have been binding from the url/querystring if StudentID is a named parameter/ known to the route

Comment: I cannot confirm this now as I have no access to VS2010 but I have just spotted that in the View the `HiddenFor()` field is outside a `using(BeginForm()){}` clause. Could this be the reason for my problem?

Comment: Confirmed! I've accidentally moved hidden fields outside the`using(Html.BeginForm()) {}`.